How to include a directory in snap filesystem sandboxing?
I use the RAM-disk mounted in /dev/shm a lot, and would like to be able to read files from there from different applications (e.g. web browsers). However, due to sandboxing of snap based applications, this is not allowed.
As reported here, it is possible to install applications in --devmode, but this has two cons:

It must be done for every application that needs access.
It grants access to everything, not just /dev/shm.

What I would like to do is to add /dev/shm to the list of directories accessible by snap based applications. Is there a way to do it?

That would defeat the whole design of snaps. Very much doubt it. What research have you done so far? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

I am using Ubuntu 24.04.

To me it looks like a much more conservative (and safe) approach than using applications built in --devmode...

Have you seen this https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/10i6m19/i_figured_out_how_to_modify_installed_snaps/ maybe you can write a script to edit the snaps if this works.

Ubuntu will use more and more snaps so something to get used too.

What I would like to do is to add /dev/shm to the list of directories accessible by snap based applications. Is there a way to do it?
You are trying to defeat a fundamental design feature of snaps (confinement).
This suggests that snaps may be the wrong tool for your current workflow.
There are two ways, but both add risk. Neither is generally acceptable for regular use.

You can use --devmode, but that will eliminate all confinement. You're giving the snap more control than necessary.
You can manually rebuild each Snap package, but your changes will revert at the next refresh.

